# Websockets using multiprocessing

Tags: sockets, websocket, multiprocessing

I am writing a file transfer program using websockets, is there any way I can increase the speed using multiprocessing? For instance, using multiple processes to create multiple websockets between two computers, splitting file in as many parts and sending each part through each process, does this increase the speed of transfer?

Answer (score 1):

No, probably you would create unnecessary overhead. The bandwidth between A and B is going to be defined by the slowest connectivity segment in the path, and it is not going to change no matter how many processes you start.

Another thing would be if you put the file parts available from different locations that are reached avoiding common slowest segments, like P2P applications do.

This may interest you: https://www.howtogeek.com/141257/htg-explains-how-does-bittorrent-work/

For example, if you have a 56K connection, no matter in how many locations you put the file parts, your download will be limited to 56K. If you have a 100Mb LAN, but your neighbor is on 56K, you can only download file parts from him at 56K. If you have another neighbor on a 10Mb line serving files, you can now download parts at 10Mb+56K, and so on. If you get another neighbor with a 1Gb line, you will be able of download at 100Mb, that is the maximum of your line. And if your 56K neighbor allows you to reach another neighbor with a crazy 100GB line, you still will be limited to 56K with him.